# Uploading a Laravel web app to hostgator

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

Can someone help me with the procedure to upload a laravel 5.3 app built on my local machine to hostgator cpanel.

Details of my app - Built locally on my home computer using xampp apache, xampp phpmyadmin. The env is currently mapped to my local xampp phpmyadmin application.

Comment: can you post your .env here ?

Comment: No sorry, I cannot. I just need to know what files need to be updated and how do I map the phpmyadmin on the web env file

Comment: actually phpmyadmin is not mapped in the .env file , it should be mapped under the Apacahe config , if you are using shared hosting like hostgator you should find the phpmyadmin on the cpanel.
The config that you need to change in .env will be realted to DB & APP_URL but phpmyadmin isn't related

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get Laravel installed on Hostgator with  help from this: 
https://www.5balloons.info/hosting-laravel-5-5-project-on-shared-hosting-hostgator/